# SQLite3 объединить ответы

Tags: sqlite3

У меня есть необходимость получить совмещенный результат выполнения двух SQL-запросов.

Пускай это будет примитив:

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id=1
SELECT role FROM table2 WHERE subject_name='Пупкин'
```

Я могу обратиться к таблице role и получить нужные мне сведения запросом

```
SELECT role FROM table2 WHERE subject_name=(SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id=1)
```

но тогда ответом будет только role из table2, но нужно еще вывести и name из table1.
Можно было бы в коде приложения использовать полученные данные из первого запроса (table1), формировать готовую таблицу и "дотягивать" для каждой строчки значение из второй таблицы (table2) новым запросов, но дорабатывать приложение возможности нет и следует решать проблему только средствами SQLite.

Также пошарив в сети я нашел оператор UNION с помощью которого можно собрать конструкцию

```
SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id=1 UNION SELECT role FROM table2 WHERE subject_name=(SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE id=1)
```

Но в таком случае возвращается ответ в виде строк таблиц:

| name |
| --- |
| 1 |
| Пупкин |

а необходимо:

| id | name | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Пупкин | Главный |

UPD: +/- структура таблиц ниже, входными данными будет только значение id из table1, результатом должна быть таблица с колонками id, role, например

table1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Пупкин |
| 2 | Не Пупкин |

table2

| role | name |
| --- | --- |
| Главный | Пупкин |
| Не главный | Не Пупкин |

Comment: Какими полями связаны таблицы?, чтобы что-то сказать нужны поля обоих таблиц и какие поля связаны.

Comment: Вы не знакомы с оператором `JOIN`?

Comment: Поправил добавив структуру. Дело в том, что отправной точкой служит значение из одной таблицы, а остальная информация должна подтягиваться из второй + id из первой, например

Comment: нет, у меня довольно скудные знания в SQL, но судя по тому, что вижу в документации мне кажется, что это может стать решением моей проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На вид это обычный `SELECT` из нескольких таблиц:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.role FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.id=1 and a.name=b.subject_name and b.subject_name='Пупкин'
```

Ну, либо через `JOIN` тоже самое:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.role FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b on a.name=b.subject_name
WHERE a.id=1 and b.subject_name='Пупкин'
```

Comment: Да, действительно, это является решением моей проблемы, спасибо!